# Isn't has a general verb when followed by an object and then Ing

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 1. The restaurant has a lot of customers **stand** in line every lunch time
> 2. The restaurant has a lot of customers **standing** in line every lunch time

I know for the fact that the verb "has" in sentence 1 functions as a causative verb like "make" or "let". But, how about the one in sentence 2?   I am not so sure.

I think the verb has in sentence 2 is not a causative verb but functions as a general verb with standing as a modifier.

Could you help me clarify it? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so so much for editing.   It is strange that the text I saw, the one before your kind editing, does not seem like the one I actually uploaded (spacing etc).   I don't know how to do it.  Any suggestion please?  Thank you.

Comment: You might have been looking at the text box, rather than the preview underneath. Also if you copy and paste from somewhere else, it can look different when rendered on Stack Exchange. Don't worry, editors are here to help with newcomers.

Comment: The first example is *syntactically* valid, but only if we assume ***has*** is equivalent to ***makes, forces, insists upon***, which isn't all that "natural" for the *specific* context. It's a slightly "formal, dated" construction which you might use in, say, *He's a very strict teacher. He has all the children stand if a lady enters the classroom* (but in casual speech, most people would probably say *He **makes** them all stand*).

Comment: Thank you. So, sentence 2 with standing in it does not sound causative, does it?

Comment: Your second example uses "have" in its 'possessive' sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a satisfactory answer has been provided in the comments.